# Export inbox subfolders in loop to pst

Tags: vba, outlook

Summary:
How do I call **`subfolders`** of the inbox without knowing what they are called? Is that even possible in the context of exporting them to a .pst?

Full Explanation:

I'm working in an Outlook Exchange 2010 environment.

I'm trying to export emails to .pst files for about 30 users. They are going from unlimited storage on the server to 1.5 GB. This is particularly unfortunate because users have files that they must keep due to policy and legal reasons. I've taken steps to reduce their size but some of these inboxes are insanely large.

Through research I found a piece of code that will export all items associated with an email account to a single .pst and I've modified that code to target a specific **`subfolder`** within that account.

Next, I'd like to be able to target a series of **`subfolders`** under the inbox. Am I able to loop through them somehow - without specifying their names? Would that work in this context? Note: I have a **`userform`** that allows them to choose which account they want to export from.

Code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub BackUpEmailInPST()
    Dim olNS As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim olBackup As Outlook.Folder
    Dim bFound As Boolean
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim strDisplayName As String
    strDisplayName = "Backup " & Format(Date, "yyyymmdd")
    strPath = "C:\Users\TaylorMat\Documents\Attachments\" & strDisplayName &         ".pst"
    Set olNS = GetNamespace("MAPI")
    olNS.AddStore strPath
    Set olBackup = olNS.Folders.GetLast
    olBackup.Name = strDisplayName
    RunBackup olNS, olBackup
    olNS.RemoveStore olBackup
lbl_Exit:
    Set olNS = Nothing
    Set olBackup = Nothing
    Exit Sub
End Sub

Sub RunBackup(olNS As Outlook.NameSpace, olBackup As Outlook.Folder)
    Dim oFrm As New frmSelectAccount
    Dim strAcc As String
    Dim olStore As Store
    Dim olFolder As Folder
    Dim olNewFolder As Folder
    Dim i As Long
    With oFrm
        .BackColor = RGB(191, 219, 255)
        .Height = 190
        .Width = 240
        .Caption = "Backup E-Mail"
        With .CommandButton1
            .Caption = "Next"
            .Height = 24
            .Width = 72
            .Top = 126
            .Left = 132
        End With
        With .CommandButton2
            .Caption = "Quit"
            .Height = 24
            .Width = 72
            .Top = 126
            .Left = 24
        End With

        With .ListBox1
            .Height = 72
            .Width = 180
            .Left = 24
            .Top = 42
            For Each olStore In olNS.Stores
                If Not olStore.DisplayName = olBackup Then
                    .AddItem olStore
                End If
            Next olStore
        End With
    With .Label1
        .BackColor = RGB(191, 219, 255)
        .Height = 24
        .Left = 24
        .Width = 174
        .Top = 6
        .Font.Size = 10
        .Caption = "Select e-mail store to backup"
        .TextAlign = fmTextAlignCenter
    End With
    .Show
    If .Tag = 0 Then GoTo lbl_Exit
    With oFrm.ListBox1
        For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
            If .Selected(i) Then
                strAcc = .List(i)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i
    End With
    Set olFolder = olNS.Stores(strAcc).GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set olNewFolder = olFolder.Folders("Export")
    olNewFolder.CopyTo olBackup
    DoEvents
    Set olFolder = olNS.Stores(strAcc).GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail)
    olFolder.CopyTo olBackup
End With
lbl_Exit:
    Unload oFrm
    Set olStore = Nothing
    Set olFolder = Nothing
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use MAPIFolder.Folders collection to loop through the child folders.

Why are you using Set olBackup = olNS.Folders.GetLast? The collection is not guaranteed to be in any particular order. Use the folder name (`olNS.Folders.Item("Folder name"))`